# MikTeX: UTF8 errors for double hyphens between citation start and end page

Tags: unicode, hyphenation, miktex2.9

In TexWorks (MikTek 2.9 - updated), I added some old chapters I wrote using LaTeX, and there are strange UTF8 errors where there are two hyphens between start page and end page.

Below is an example of an error.

in citations! Package utf8x Error: Character150appearedalone.

See the utf8x package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.235 ...d \textit{J.\ of ....}. 32:17-�

Comment: quite possibly the files are not in utf8 (its better to avoid utf8x and use the standard utf8 handling) but its impossible to tell from the fragment of error shown

Comment: In addition to David's comment. Sometimes when you copy and paste text it might come with some ghost invisible character the your codification does not recognize. I have also had problems with some traces.
A suggestion is to remove the whole paragraph with the issue until find out what is causing it.

Comment: I found that if I delete the 2 hyphens and retype them, the errors are not thrown.  Must be some ghosting, but did open the files with Notepad+ and there didn't seem to be anything strange that was hidden.

Comment: It's likely that what you cut and pasted had something other than an ascii hyphen.  It might be a unicoded en-dash -- in an editor buffer that isn't easy to distinguish from a hyphen, but trying to run it through LaTeX will let you know.  To fix, just delete the "hyphens" and retype.

Comment: that's what I'm thinking. I did go back to the original utf8 package like @David Carlisle said.